# If black hole is equivalent to a planet of same mass for a distant observer, then why does 'excess radius formula' require uniform mass density?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

I understand that

1. the spacetime curvature of a non-rotating, uncharged black hole is identical to that of a planet with same mass/energy for an observer at a distance farther than the radius of the planet,
2. the radius excess of a sphere (actual distance of the surface of the sphere from its center *minus* radius predicted by measuring the surface area of the sphere) with *uniform* mass (or energy) density is directly proportional to the total mass/energy contained in the sphere.

According to 1, we can radially shrink the sphere discussed in 2 without altering the space-time curvature of the region beyond the initial radius of the sphere. So, the radius excess equation should not be needing *uniform mass (or energy) density* for the sphere. In other words, if the mass in a sphere is non-uniformly distributed, then the *average* excess radius should be proportional to the *total* mass/energy contained in the sphere.

What is confusing me is the fact that wherever I read about the radius excess equation, it is firmly asserted that the density of the sphere should be uniform.

Comment: The radial excess at a distance $R$ is obtained by integrating the metric from $r = 0$ to $r = R$ in a radial direction. Inside the spherical body the metric will be different for different mass distributions. If the mass distribution is uniform it takes a simple form - the Schwarzschild interior metric. More complex mass distributions probably have to be integrated numerically. That may be why the examples you have seen require uniform density. Is this what you were asking? It isn't clear from what you've written what your question is.

Comment: My question is that suppose i know that there is m amount of mass/energy in a sphere but i do not know if it is uniformly distributed or not. Will the 'average excess radius' be still the same?

Comment: No. The excess radius will depend on the metric and the metric will depend on the mass distribution.

Comment: This means my statement (1) is wrong because the mass of the planet could be non uniformly oriented.

Comment: Your statement (1) is true as long as the mass distribution inside the planet is spherically symmetric. It doesn't have to be uniform, i.e. the density can depend on $r$, but there must be no dependence on $\theta$ or $\phi$.

Comment: Firmly read where?

Comment: Feynman lectures in physics, volume-2, last chapters. There was also some website asserting the same... My line of thinking asserts that if a black hole is the same as a spherically uniform body for a distant observer, so should be the excess radius...

Comment: I will quote from Feynman lectures: "If there is a region of space with matter in it and we take a sphere small enough that the density p of matter inside it is effectively constant, then the radius excess for the sphere is proportional to the mass inside the sphere. Suppose we take the earth as an example and forget that the density varies from point to point—so we won’t have to do any integrals..." What kind of integral does it refers to? Simple integration of all point masses leading to the actual proper mass of earth? John Rennie writes that we integrate the metric. Is that the same thing?